# Django DB optimisation filter hits by ip and 1 hour difference

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7, mysql-python

Hi I need get the count from `visits` on my DB, this `visits` are hits from different ips and 1 hour minimum difference, I get it right now with this code:

```
visits = get_visits_number(App_hit.objects.filter(app_id__campaign_id__agency_id=agency).all())

def get_visits_number(hits):
if hits:
    ips = {}
    date = {}
    for hit in hits:
        if hit.hit.remote_addr in ips:
            if hit.hit.created > date[hit.hit.remote_addr]  + timedelta(hours=1):
                ips[hit.hit.remote_addr] = ips[hit.hit.remote_addr] + 1
                date[hit.hit.remote_addr] = hit.hit.created
        else:
            ips[hit.hit.remote_addr] = 1
            date[hit.hit.remote_addr] = hit.hit.created

    total = 0
    for ip in ips:
        total = total + ips[ip]

    return total

return 0
```

But if have more than 4.000 hits this takes a lot, over 30 seconds, exist any suggestion for make better and faster code?

Comment: You could make an stored procedure to return just the right data and not all the data, because filtering the data in code just feel wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried some work around. Haven't found some significant good solutions. The point is that, regardless you query statement, your get_visits_number is basically linear. There is a certain more neat way to write the code, but no improvement to the performance.

However, what is really bothering me is that hit.hit.remote_addr. First 'hit' should be instance of App_hit, right? Then what is the second 'hit'? Another instance? A foreign key of App_hit? A potential issue you may have is that hit.hit (if it is not a typo) will cause one more database hit for retrieving data from hit.hit. You may want to use select_related in your Django query which will retrieve all the data at once.

Second possible solution, you may don't like it, as Robert Rozas said, you should try to put as much as possible data manipulation operation into query (which may not possible, though). DB is much faster than your python parser. If standardized Django ORM cannot satisfy you, then you can try raw sql query, which is hard to write and maintain. raw sql query will certainly boost your running speed, if you really care that much.

Comment: Thanks for reply, the first hit is a App_hit reference, the second is a foreign key of the hit table, I don't know how "select_related" works but I go to make a research.

¿You think I can save a lot of resources if I save the "remote_addr" in App_hit? (for referencing hit.remote_addr instead hit.hit.remote_addr)

The second'm currently analysing.

Comment: Your right with select_related speed up to 5 seconds THANKS.

Comment: if you would, hit.remote_addr is certainly better than hit.hit.remote_addr (even with select_related). The real meat of your code is the for loop. I tried to integrate it (partially) into query, but failed. That is why I mentioned raw sql, although that is not a good idea.

Comment: You're right again hit.remote_addr speed up like 50% over select_related, thanks.